# PostgreSQL: How to get a daterange with inclusive end date?

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to tell PostgreSQL to output a daterange with an inclusive end date?

For example, if I run this:

`SELECT '[2016-09-01,2016-09-10]'::daterange`

The output is:

`[2016-09-01,2016-09-11)`

This is really annoying, since what I get back from the database does not match what I put in.

Comment: You do get back what you put in. Both ranges are identical. `'[2016-09-01,2016-09-10]'::daterange = '[2016-09-01,2016-09-11)'::daterange` yields `true`

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is intentional and has solid reasons.
The `daterange` is a discrete range type what means that it changes all input values to their canonical form.
This makes it possible to compare the same ranges in various forms:

```
select '[2016-09-01,2016-09-10]'::daterange = '[2016-09-01,2016-09-11)'::daterange;
-- yields true
```

You could create your own range type:

```
create type mydaterange as range
   (subtype=date,
    subtype_diff=daterange_subdiff);

select '[2016-09-01,2016-09-10]'::daterange, '[2016-09-01,2016-09-10]'::mydaterange

        daterange        |       mydaterange       
-------------------------+-------------------------
 [2016-09-01,2016-09-11) | [2016-09-01,2016-09-10]
(1 row)
```

but it makes little sense as in this case

```
select '[2016-09-01,2016-09-10]'::mydaterange = '[2016-09-01,2016-09-11)'::mydaterange;
-- yields false!
```

Read about [Discrete Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE).

Comment: To make your last query return true, you could/should provide a `canonical` function for the new range type. However, I can't find any examples of how to write such functions or documentation except that it is ["a bit tricky"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html). Writing such a [function appears to require C](https://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/127hd0rnzv/chicken-egg-problem-with-range-types) (may have changed since 2012).